# Copy all files from multiple subfolders into a folder on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, file-management, file-transfer

I have downloaded over 7000 ebooks from Gutenburg, but the issue is is that they are all in zip files. and each of these zip files is in its own folder. I am trying to move all of the zip files into a folder called ebooks, and after that I can unzip the files to reveal the text files.

Comment: 7000 ebooks? if you read one a day, every day, that's 20 years of reading!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're all subdirectories of a single folder:

Open a terminal and enter: `unzip /path/to/your/directory/*/* -d /your/target/directory/`

If your hierarchy is more complicated than that, it would be worth your while (and 1-UP your Unix pwnage skills) to read into the `unzip man` page (`man unzip`).